# window.print() calls idletimer when done, only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a page that has an idletimer set to log you out after 20 minutes:

```
               (function($){

                    var clientTimeoutInMinutes = 20; // hard-coded as requirements ask for 20 minutes

                    $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
                      form = document.FormOSDA;
                      form.TargetPage.value = "Logout";
                      form.action="myactionpage";
                      form.submit();
                    });
                    $.idleTimer(clientTimeoutInMinutes * 60 * 1000); // convert to  milli secs

                })(jQuery);
```

But in Chrome, and only in Chrome, this is being called after I do a window.print(), even if they immediately cancel the print dialog.  This happens with the most recent Chrome on Windows XP and Mac, and doesn't happen with IE 8 or Firefox.

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: before going any further, logout timeout should always be done in the server-side to guarantee security. If it's done in the user side, there's always room for security breaches.

Comment: it's done both places.  The idle timer just means they see the 'you've been logged out' screen before they make a bunch of changes on the form and hit submit.

Comment: I would use window focus, blur, and document mousemove and simply use `window.location.href='logout.html'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found it as a bug report in the [jquery-idletimer](https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer) plugin we're using, fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a plugin for it: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timeout_interval_idle or even plain javascript -> setTimeout()